# In python, how can i use a loop to name panda data frames?

Tags: python, pandas

What I'm trying to do is to use pandas to create as many separate data arrays as there are runs of my data set. The approach needs to be vary depending on the data file read in, so I want the run number, the second column, to be used to identify the data and separate it into separate data sets.

So I have a data set that looks like:

```
1.350000035018e-03  1.000000000000e+00  -1.617387196395e-14
2.850000048056e-03  1.000000000000e+00  -2.752685546875e-06
4.350000061095e-03  1.000000000000e+00  -2.062988281250e-06
(couple hundred lines later)
1.350000035018e-03  2.000000000000e+00  -1.617387196395e-14
2.850000048056e-03  2.000000000000e+00  -2.752685546875e-06
4.350000061095e-03  2.000000000000e+00  -2.062988281250e-06
(however many readings later)
1.350000035018e-03  35.000000000000e+00 -1.617387196395e-14
2.850000048056e-03  35.000000000000e+00 -2.752685546875e-06
4.350000061095e-03  35.000000000000e+00 -2.062988281250e-06
```

I want to process it into:

```
data1 = some number 1.0 some number
        some number 1.0 some number

data2 = some number 2.0 some number
        some number 2.0 some number

datan= some number n some number
       some number n some number
```

So far my code:

```
    f =r'C:~.dat'
    
    #store data using pandas
    data = pd.read_csv( f, sep = '\t', comment = '#', names = ['V','n','I'] )
    
    #observe data format
    print(data)
    
                 V     n             I
    0      0.001350   1.0 -1.617387e-14
    1      0.002850   1.0 -2.752686e-06
    2      0.004350   1.0 -2.062988e-06
    
    
    
    
    #count the loops for autamted graph plotting
    num = 1
    for i in range (len(data)):
        if i > 0:
            if data['n'][i]> data['n'][i-1]:
                num = num + 1
    #
    print('there are '+str(num)+' runs')
    
    #seperate data based on loop #n
    for i in range (num):
        
        run = data.groupby(data.n)
        data+str(i) = run.get_group(i)
        print(data+str(i))
    #
```

using the data grouping method works, but I cant figure out a way to use the loop number as a name variable, any help/suggestions would be highly appreciated?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, so I have a 2K + set of data that consists of three columns, the middle collumn is a run count and increaces by 1 at the end of each set of data collection.

Comment: I want to process that data to separate into data frames that consist of only those that match for that run, the order of those values must also be kept in tact. However between the data files I have the length of each run and the number of runs is inconsistent.   As a result I want to make a script that will seperate the data by runs but also include the run number in the name, or some similar method of distinguishing the results.

Comment: Instead of putting this information in the comment, it is better to add this to the question, that makes it more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to explicitly name your dataframes or can it be part of a list or dict?

For instance, you could do something like this...

```
import pandas as pd

f =r'C:~.dat'
   
#store data using pandas
data = pd.read_csv( f, sep = '\t', comment = '#', names = ['V','n','I'] )

data_list = []
# get unique run entries
runs = data["n"].unique()

# save each run's corresponding dataframe into data_list
for run in runs:
    data_sub = data[data["n"] == run]
    data_list.append(data_sub)

# access it by doing something as follows
for idx, run in enumerate(runs):
    print("Working on run {}".format(run))
    df_to_operate_on = data_list[idx]
```

Comment: maybe, i need to use the following to then plot overlapping graphs to make use of the data, would that be easily achievable this way?

Comment: If your purpose for separating the dataframes is for plotting, you can simply use the logic  in `for run in runs:` loop directly and use the dataframe subset as your plot source.

Comment: Thanks I've got the idea, and it sort of works, There not very distinguishable though, being the same colour.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve. But if you aim to have data like this:

```
1.350000035018e-03  1  -1.617387196395e-14
2.850000048056e-03  2  -2.752685546875e-06
4.350000061095e-03  3  -2.062988281250e-06
```

do you really need the `n` column?
Isn't that just the `data.index` + 1?
(the index in your example is `[0, 1, 2]`, and you're looking for `[1, 2, 3]`, so you might be able to do something like `data.n = [i + 1 for i in data.index]`)

Comment: sorry, I feel ive not been clear enough as this isnt at all what I'm getting at. Thanks tho, I've updated my post in an attempt to be clearer.